# SELECT lock only for inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, isolation-level, hints

I need to get the `MAX` aggregate of certain field in a transaction. I use this value further inside the transaction. I want to avoid inserts in the entire table from which I'm getting the `MAX` while the transaction is completed.

I researched the isolation modes and lock hints available. The closest seems to be `TABLOCKX`, which is the only one that avoids inserts in the entire table (also updates and selects).

Since I no will be affected by updates or selects in the table I wish to avoid only inserts during the transaction.  This is possible?

UPDATE: The field on wich the `MAX` is performed is seted only on inserts, thus there's no risk of get stale results for updates.

I'm using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I hope you are not doing this to generate the next ID of some sort. If you are, this is a really bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, locks are bad in general, but needed sometimes.

Comment: I'd put it this way: Locks are not bad. Unnecessary lock are bad. Identity columns and sequences should be used to generate ID values, then locking won't be an issue.

Comment: To be honest it didn't occur to me that was likely being used for a sequence generator. If that is the case I echo @mustaccio's comment, bad form.

Comment: If this were the case (isn't) the answer will be different?  I get evangelized about the horrors of get the id with MAX in the first comment, no need to insist on this.

Comment: @Apocatastasis It would far more helpful to others (and to you since all these people are trying to help you) to either add the transaction code in your question or describe what problem you are trying to solve (what the whole transaction really does) and not only the very narrow sub-problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the isolation level to [SERIALIZABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would have the same effect:

> The highest isolation level, serializable, guarantees that a
>   transaction will retrieve exactly the same data every time it repeats
>   a read operation, but it does this by performing a level of locking
>   that is likely to impact other users in multi-user systems.

`TABLOCK` will suffice, there is no need for `TABLOCKX` to achieve what you've described so far. If the transaction you mention later updates or inserts to the table then `TABLOCKX`, if it's just to read for the `MAX` it's unnecessary and other processes will at least be able to read from the table.

Whether you use the isolation level or `TABLOCK` hint depends on what proportion of the table you will be scanning to find the `MAX` aggregate. If you need to touch any significant percentage of the rows `TABLOCK` is logical. A small percentage and a desire to maintain some degree of concurrency then try `SERIALIZABLE`. `TABLOCK` would also eliminate the deadlock risk.

Both options would achieve your aim of preventing an inconsistent result from the aggregate.

Comment: I think this isn't true for selects.  A serializable transaction sets a shared lock on selects.  Only in modifications exclusive locks are raised. http://improve.dk/solving-deadlocks-through-locking-hints/

Comment: A serializable transaction will only block if a modification occurs. Regardless, a TABLOCK(X) is obviously going to do exactly the same. Perhaps you need to re-phrase your question slightly, am I misunderstanding your objective?

Comment: TABLOCKX issues an exclusive lock, even for selects.  Serializable <> TABLOCKX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx

Comment: Sorry, let me try type that again while paying attention... A serializable transaction will only block if a modification occurs. Regardless, a TABLOCK (not X) is obviously going to do exactly the same. Perhaps you need to re-phrase your question slightly, am I misunderstanding your objective?

Comment: I only need to avoid insert in the entire table during a transaction originated in a SELECT statement, allowing selects and updates.  Neither TABLOCKX hint or SERIALIZABLE isolation do this.  I'm asking if there's a way to achieve this, but seems that isn't possible.  The only way to avoid inserts in a table is to issue an exclusive lock, and for SELECT the only way to achieve this is the TABLOCKX hint, wich also blocks selects and updates.

Comment: No, that is not possible. That a modification to a row is the result of an update or an insert is irrelevant here. But you are incorrect that the only way to avoid an insert is with an exclusive lock. A shared lock achieves the same, you cannot insert or update a row when it is protected by a shared lock by another transaction.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9533/discussion-between-apocatastasis-and-mark-storey-smith)

Answer (score 3):

Per [Mark's determination](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45758/2718), this isn't possible using locking hints or isolation level.

If all the `INSERT`s you care about go through predetermined code paths, you can use a [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933410%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)-based mechanism to serialize them while still allowing normal access to the table during the operation.

It would be preferable to simply use an `IDENTITY` column for this purpose, though, as the generated values are automatically serialized for you.

Comment: I can't go this way, since I'm using SQL Server 2000.  I'm updating my question.  +1 for an alternative out of hints and isolation level.

Comment: @Apocatastasis: The current documentation site I linked to doesn't include SQL 2000 because support is over. I've updated my answer to include a link to the correct documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your data maybe it would be more useful for you to create a 2nd instance of the data. If it's small maybe just chuck the required columns and rows into a #temporary table. If it's larger then set up a separate DB as a DataMart that only you populate. Suck all the data in you require, then operate on it safe that nothing else will be adding to it.